# merging two select queries' results in one row result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two select queries. I want to merge their results in one single row; I don't want to use `union` or `union all`... Because they are not merging results in one row! How can I handle it? I have tried the following, without success.

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT * from employee
  ) ,  
  (select * from products
  ) ;
```

Comment: Look into joining tables.

Comment: No I'm not joining based on any columns; their results are not relevant but for some reason they need to be in one row!

Comment: How many rows are in the first and in the second table? How many rows do you want to get back in the result? Post some sample data and expected/desired result.

Comment: You want all the rows from either table in one row??

Comment: I'm sad for down votes:( but my queries were not that much simple; each of them was complicated query! I solved it this way, anyway: 

SELECT * from (select query1) as a
join (select query2) as b

Comment: Check my answer. if you think that would be helpful.

Comment: Voting to close due to insufficient information. The only way you'll get one row out of two disjoint tables is to *join* them on some criteria and then collapse them somehow. If you could give us a clear problem statement, sample data and expected results, it will help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help; now it is solved :-) I used the query that I mentioned in my last comment here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you mean something like this (if my understanding to the question is correct)

```
select emp.*,prd.* 
from employee emp 
inner join products prd
on emp.employee_id = prd.id
limit 1 <-- to get you only 1 row
```

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty simple.

```
select * 
from employee e 
join products p on e.some_column1 = p.some_column2
```

**UPDATE**

```
select * from 
(select * from tbl1) p1
join 
(select * from tbl2) p2 on 1=1
```

Here I assume tbl1 and tbl2 are the results from
your 2 complex expressions which return 2 result sets
containing 1 row each.

And ... probably you can even simplify this a bit.

```
select * from tbl1 p1
join 
(select * from tbl2) p2 on 1=1
```

Comment: No I'm not joining based on any columns; their results are not releavant but for some reason they need to be in one row!

Comment: Then if you like, you can omit the `on e.some_column1 = p.some_column2` part.

Comment: Yes I want them in one row @peter.petrov: I have simplified my question with a simple select * from employee but in fact each of my query is a complicated query with lots of joins and their results(both queries) have just a one row result!

Comment: Now I got it, let me write you the answer.